# If I delete Azure Data Lake Analytics Account will it delete it's Default Data Source?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I'm fairly new to Azure, and just trying out Azure Data Lake Analytics.

I created a new Azure Data Lake Analytics account for testing purposes and would like to delete it now, however I used an existing Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) account as the *default storage account* during setup. I now know I probably should have added the existing ADLS as *associated data store*.

I assume I can safely delete the Azure Data Lake Analytics account now without affecting the underlying default storage account, but I want to check before I do this as it would be a massive problem if this the existing ADLS gets deleted.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Azure Data Lake Team here. I can positively confirm that deleting the Azure Data Lake Analytics account will NOT delete the default or any linked Azure Data Lake Store account associated with it.

Comment: Great thanks for clearing that up. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The two are separate. Deleting the Azure Data Lake Analytics service will not affect the Azure Data Lake Store.

As a disclaimer, test test test. Set up another instance of both in the same way and then confirm the delete behaviour, just to be 110% sure.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for answering so quickly. Really appreciate